# LASSO method for multiple imputed datasets and categorical outcome variable

Tags: imputation, lasso-regression

I have been endlessly searching for an answer and would really appreciate any help. I currently have 10 imputed datasets, a categorical outcome variable (ordinal, three levels), a categorical exposure variable, and a mix of covariates (numerical, categorical, binary). I would like to apply a LASSO method in order to select which variables should be included into the final multinomial logistic regression model, but I have not found any papers that have addressed this topic or provided R code for how to perform this. I have found many papers that show which procedure can be done if you have a binary or continous outcome but not a categorical outcome. Does anyone have any resources?
Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I got, that you have got m=10 imputed datasets and you want to do variable selection / apply Lasso.

I am not quite sure, if the problem is in creating the lasso model for each of the datasets or if the problem is pooling the m=10 lasso results together.

Well, the overall idea of multiple imputation is (as you probably know) to have these **m** slightly different imputed datasets to account for the uncertainty introduced by the estimation of the missing values. On these **m** datasets you independently perform your analysis (in your case 10 times). Afterwards you **pool** the **m** results together. As you know for certain tasks / models there are accepted/existing pooling rules (see Rubins Rules to pool parameter estimates, e.g. mean differences, regression coefficients, standard errors and to derive confidence intervals and p-values.)

So what you want to do is perform your lasso on all your m imputed datasets and then pool the results.

Don't know if the pooling or the lasso was the problem...
(are you you using R?)

In R with **glmnet** the lasso would look like this example.

```
library(glmnet)

testdata <- iris[-c(2,3),]
x_vars <- model.matrix(Species ~. , testdata)
y_var <- testdata$Species
cv_output <- cv.glmnet(x_vars, y_var,
                       alpha = 1, 
                       nfolds = 5, family = "multinomial")
coef(cv_output)
```

Call to `model.matrix` to expanding factors to a set of dummy variables. In `cv.glmnet` use `family = "multinomial"` for your categorical outcome. Use `alpha = 1` for lasso.

Well, that's basically the lasso part I guess. Then `coef(cv_output)` to see which parameters are n the model.

The pooling is a different beast. I also don't know existing R implementations ... which would mean you have to do it on your own.

There are different approaches and I don't think there is a consensus in literature, which one is the best. Stef van Buuren (the mice developer) gives a good  [overview](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-stepwise.html).

I personally find the 'Brand (1999, chap. 7)' approach mentioned in the overview sounds sensible.

> The first step involves performing stepwise model selection separately
> on each imputed dataset, followed by the construction of a new
> supermodel that contains all variables that were present in at least
> half of the initial models. [...]